# Opposite leaves/instances on spline

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am wondering if anybody has a better way to do this. My solution seems rather complex and convoluted for what I'm trying to accomplish.  The challenge was to generate a branch with double leaves on opposite sides of a curving stem with phyllo-taxis rotation. Much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your curve to points before instancing on them, rather than using the curve's implicit points, then the *Curve to Points*  node gives you useful information. Including 'Rotation', which includes the tilt of the curve at the points.

So.. if you capture the curve's 0-1 *Spline Parameter > Factor*, and set the tilt of the curve to be a function of it:

[image]

.. the tilt will be picked up by *Curve to Points*, and can be passed on to set the rotation of instances on the points in an *Instance on Points* node:

[image]

In this tree, the spline parameter is used in other ways, too...

- To set the density of distribution of points on the curve, making leaf-pairs closer together at the top
- To set the scale of the leaf-pairs
- To vary the thickness of the stem along its length

[image]

Like this:

[image]

[image]

This is a version with stricter rotation to tangent, in response to @LGood's commentary:

[image]

Comment: I like your nodes and the way you explain them!

Comment: @quellenform Thank you! It's a puzzle, isn't it? It's a real slog tidying up big node trees to make them BSE-useful. I like the way Kuboå does it..

Comment: I am honestly amazed.  Amazed that I got an answer and can learn form it. And less than 24hrs after I asked.  I only hope I could be so useful to others on here some day.

Comment: Since I have done very little trigonometry or math in general since college (30 years ago now) it will take me some time to truly understand the multiply-add nodes here.  Regardless strictly speaking about how plant growth works there is an issue with this as it is.  The leaves don't really follow the tangent of the curve equally and thus in some instances they occur on the side of the stem - I'd upload images to describe what I mean but apparently I can't do so in comments.  Curiously the leaf orientation works better if you instance a bezier created manually as the starting curve.

Comment: Yes on second thought - as part of the ultimate project I'm working on - the leaves would want to face the sun - or an object influence in Blender.  Basically what I'm trying to do is re-create what I've been doing in GrowFX/3DS to create realistic plant  models.  Your solution above is close to that in that the leaves generally face the same direction.

Comment: @LGood Okydoky.. see edit for what I hope is a fix to the problem you're talking about? If not.. call back. Late here, now, so if _not_ a fix, will get to it tomorrow. :)  I think it looks less lively, but I shouldn't let my personal taste get in the way of the math!

Comment: Yes - great I see now.  You've got me stumped again however.  I can't seem to instance these leaves on multiple curve instances as I was able to do with my first attempt.  Ex - instance curves on a mesh -> instance leaves on curves. https://imgur.com/a/O2NuaCL

Comment: @LGood  Will cjheck it out today

Comment: @LGood It's got me stumped too.. the behaviour of _Sample Curve_ is bizarre AFAICS, to the point of being a bug.  It's something I want to solve for myself, so will work on it.

Comment: Well - It seems the curve to points turns the entire lot into a single field of points and thus they are treated that way afterward. I've made it work by not using it in this context.  I learned a lot from the other components you created though

Comment: @LGood Bit busy atm to get buried in it... If I I can't get there, I'll try to frame a Q of my own ..