# Whorled Leaves on a beveled curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm searching for a way to create whorled leaves/branches around parent branches that are beveled curves (curve to mesh with profile curve circle).  The approach shown generates strange results with the instances twisting.  I think I understand why but don't know a solution that allows a) the leaves to be radially arrayed without twisting and b) allows the angle from the branch to be adjustable by a factor of the spline length.

[image]
[image]

Comment: just a dumb question: do you want a solution or an explanation? if first: just do the instancing before curve to mesh

Comment: Chris. Instancing before curve to mesh produces only 1 instance per curve point which is not the 'point'.  This is part of a larger project to place branches as well as leaves on the surface of other branches via the 3 phyllo taxis types - single, opposite, whorled.  Instancing before the curve to mesh would place leaves and smaller branches inside parent branches.  A solution or an explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262058/35559)?

Comment: Robin - yes The opposite leaves solution works and was a big step forward for me - thank you. but there are issues with this.  1) it does not work work with multiple curve instances as the Sample Curve node turns all instances into a single field of points. 2) the leaves are not instanced on the stem but on the spline which will be a problem in some cases with small leaves on larger branches. 3) there doesn't seem to be a way to change the leaf angle from the stem as a factor of the parent spline length - leaves on the tips are typically at smaller angle from the stem than lower down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following suggestion for you:

[image]

[image]

However, I still want to leave some of your homework to you, so I'll only outline my suggestion very roughly:

1. First I create a simple curve, and save the factor with the node `Capture Attribute`. This should first influence the radius, and later the scaling and the rotation. I bent the value for the radius here additionally with the node `Float Curve` and the node `Map Range` in such a way that it corresponds to some extent to the needed form.

   [image]
2. Then I instantiate a polygon at the points of the curve. Since you wanted to position the individual leaves with a certain distance to the stem, this seems to me to be a workable solution.

   [image]
3. In the next step I instantiate the leaves and use the node `Float Curve` again, but this time to influence the rotation upwards depending on the curve factor on the one hand, and to change the scaling of the leaves on the other hand. As a basis for the rotation, I use the tangents that were previously supplied by Curve to Points.

   [image]

[image]

Comment: Great - thank you for your time and excellent response.  I had tried something similar but got hung up on the fact that euler rotations were lost once 'realized instances' was used.  I will study this and try and implement into the larger algorithm with phyllotaxis rotation, noise applied to the stem etc.